# Tarpaulin reports log::info() lines as uncovered. How to ignore trace call in code coverage?

Tags: rust, code-coverage

Running code coverage in Rust with tarpaulin.

Tarpaulin executes the same test cases as `cargo test` which does not print debug traces e.g. `log::info()` and `log::warn()` in the original code. Since the traces are turned off code will not be generated for them and the lines never gets covered by the tests. The metric we look for is how well covered the code is by our test cases.

I know it is possible to to use `#[cfg_attr(tarpaulin, ignore)]` to ignore some code but it would not harm readability to prepend all logs with this.

***How to turn off tarpaulin code coverage for*** `log::info()`?

Comment: Maybe you can create a function/macro that calls `info` and uses `cfg`?

Comment: You can ignore the entire log module if you own it with `#![cfg_attr(tarpaulin, skip)]`.

Comment: This will not work, line coverage is reported on the line calling `log::info` not in the function itself. I will edit with an example to show

Comment: Did you have the chance to find something @Simson? I am having the same issue

Comment: No I don't think I solved this, still an annoyance